# Is おにょみ a valid spelling/pronunciation of 音読み?

Tags: spelling

I assume the answer is no.

I am asking, because my IME (Mozc) converts おにょみ into 音読み (same with くにょみ→訓読み).

I think this is simply a matter of convenience to save the user from having to press `[n]` twice, but I can't think of any other word where this kind of feature is implemented.

So is there anything more to this?

Comment: Another way to type the word is _on'yomi_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

おにょみ does not make sense except as deliberate 変換ミス (e.g. for comical effect).

Handling such mistypes is a common IME feature for words with ん+ vowel combinations or ん+な行.

[image: IME settings screenshot]

As shown in the screenshot, another common example is おんあ(onna)→女.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to Igor's answer, which addresses the spelling aspect.  Let's look at the pronunciation.

> Is おにょみ a valid pronunciation of 音読み?

In a word, no.

- おんよみ is pronounced something like [[õ̞.ɰ̃.jo̞.mi]] in normal speech.  This has four distinct [morae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mora_(linguistics)) ("beats", the timed length of sounds in Japanese).  The ん between two vowels causes nasalization, marked by the tilde ~, with the specific mora of the ん often realized as something like a tight //u// sound with nasalization: technically, [[ɰ̃]], a nasalized [voiced velar approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_approximant).
- Meanwhile, おにょみ would be pronounced as something more like [[o̞.ɲ̟ʲo̞.mi]].  This has only three distinct morae, and no nasalization.

音読み is only ever spelled in kana as おんよみ, with four kana corresponding to the four morae, and with ん correctly indicating the nasal consonant.